# Proxy environment variables for java.net.URL

Tags: scala, proxy, playframework

In my Play 2 app, I am calling a Scala wrapper around java.net.URL, [Bee Client](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client). According to the docs, `java.net.URL` supports proxy but I can't find the details on how and what to set for environment variables.

I have tried, without success,

```
export proxySet=true
export proxyHost=my-proxy-server
export proxyPort=1080
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATED:**
After digging further, they aren't environment variables but rather JVM command line arguments as also noted by Rick. However, I have tried the following also without success

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-server -Dhttp.proxyPort=1080"
sbt -Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-server -Dhttp.proxyPort=1080 test
```

Note that I am passing the arguments to `sbt test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I also need to pass the socks proxy setting, could be specific to my company's network but here is what works for me

```
sbt -Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-server -Dhttp.proxyPort=1080 -DsocksProxyHost=my-socks-proxy-server test
```

Answer (score 6):

The properties you are looking to set are:

```
http.proxyHost
http.proxyPort
```

and if you need authentication, you can also set these:

```
http.nonProxyHosts
http.proxyUser
http.proxyPassword
```

They are not environment variables in your OS, so you'd pass them to the JVM via -D at startup, or in your app with `System.setProperty`. That should allow URL to connect via a proxy server.

This page has a pretty good summary on the properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Answer (score 1):

I have added [a new tutorial page](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/content/bee-client/making-requests-via-proxies) to the Bee Client documentation on how to make requests via proxies. (Thanks for the suggestion.)

Comment: Thanks Rick, I have already tried using command line arguments but still couldn't get it to work. Please check my updated question for details. Any additional suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure how SBT passes on -D flags to its code under test. Apparently you've found it doesn't work. How about using System.setProperty in your test's setup code instead? I'm presuming you would prefer not to use a Proxy in the Config passed into HttpClient.

Comment: I got it to work, see my answer below. In my case, I have to also pass the socks proxy setting.